# Supersede users need to press enter after inputting a string in python 3.0

Tags: python, input

I've been attempting to create a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game in python 3.0 -- very standard task for anybody learning programming.

But, as I finish up to a point, I think,"wow, that'd be awesome", or,"it'd be cool to do this!" So anyways, I keep building upon the project...

I've developed a menu, a single player game vs the computer, and just finished the multiplayer game. But, I've realized, that the multiplayer game isn't very effective. It just dosen't work like the analog version of the game.

Currently, it'll ask for player1's input, then player2's input, compare them, and spit out the result and the current score. What I'd rather have happen is that the program asks for both players input at the same time and both players input their choice at the same time.

I understand that I can easily do that by just grabbing the index of the first and second answer and compare the 2 inputs -- easy. But what I'd rather have happen is that after both players enter their one character answers at the same time (r for rock, p for paper, or s for scissors), then the program will auto enter the input. Not needing someone to press enter.

The input would be dictated by the fact that 2 characters have been entered.

I guess my question is:
Is there any way to dictate what can be used as an input for 'enter'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [`msvcrt.getch()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html).

If you only need it for Windows, it's quite simple:

```
from msvcrt import getch
letter1 = getch()
letter2 = getch()        
print("Pressed", letter1, "and", letter2)
```

For Linux it's a bit more complicated:

```
import sys, tty, termios
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

letter1 = getch()
letter2 = getch()        
print("Pressed", letter1, "and", letter2)
```

Notice they don't echo the letter pressed. This may actually be beneficial for this game if both players are on the same computer, but you can always print it manually after receiving the value.

For a cross platform solution that uses polymorphism to select the correct version, check this recipe:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/